# how to submit a form with submit button outside form

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, button

i already used all possible scripts and i cannot click this button

[image]

element location

Submit

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Where is your code attempts? please share a link to the web page, not a picture.

Comment: Post your code attempts (a minimal reproducible example), and also confirm the url, and you will get a better chance of receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try webelement in selenium Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value'] ?[image]

Comment: I have tried it now and it is not working

Comment: It should work with xpath, Try both rel-xpath or abs-xpath. If not something went wrong with ur code. Plz send ur codes.